# ASP.NET MVC4 routing issue with cache,manifest file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to generate cache.manifest file automatically. Therefore I created a controller and an action accessible by /OfflineSupport/Manifest. Everything works fine. The content is delivered correctly.

Now I want to register this action when I call cache.manifest. That's why I added a new route. My RegisterRoutes method looks as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );

    routes.MapRoute("cache.manifest", "cache.manifest", new { controller = "OfflineSupport", action = "Manifest" });
}
```

My site runs under localhost:7365/. When I call localhost:7365/cache.manifest, I get a 404.0 with following detailed information:
module: IIS Web Core, message: MapRequestHandler, handler: StaticFile, errorcode: 0x80070002.

And the action is never called. Any suggestions what to change to get correct routing?

Comment: when I move the mapping at the beginning and change url to cache (without manifest extension) it works.

so the problem is the extension. how to force the routing to not serve this by staticfilehandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the period is the problem. Whenever I map to a route containing a period ASP.NET MVC tries to find a physical file. When I remove the period everything works fine.
So it seems not to be possible to do what I wanted to do and I will map to routes without a period in future.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to modify the web.config to include:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

This will allow periods in the routes and non query-string-defined (`?`) parameters.

Answer (score 0):

the order of the routes defined is also important.

try to move your custom route above the default route declaration.

Comment: it doesn't matter. tried it at the beginning, in between of the two standard statements and at the end.